# Is it possible to use SAS 9.3 enhanced editor for windows 8?

Tags: sas

After searching, I got two different answers. See the following link: 
http://support.sas.com/kb/44/495.html#Try

and

http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2013/11/06/sas-on-windows-8/

Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [SAS Supported Operating Systems page](http://support.sas.com/supportos/list), SAS 9.3 [is supported on Windows 8.1](http://support.sas.com/supportos/list?requestAction=summary&outputView=sasrelease&sasrelease=9.3&platformGroup=Windows&platformName=Windows+8.1) as well as [8](http://support.sas.com/supportos/list?requestAction=summary&outputView=sasrelease&sasrelease=9.3&platformGroup=Windows&platformName=Windows+8). Your TS note above refers to a common problem when installing 9.3 over an old 9.2 installation, but doesn't mean it's not supported (and in fact has an explanation of the way to solve that particular problem).

I would encourage you to contact your SAS support representative with site-specific details if you are unsure, however; that's why they are there.

Comment: That supported OS system page is a bit buggy - it gave me two different answers on raw 8.  I think this one is 'right' though - I had searched for 9.1.3 earlier to test and I wonder if it forgot that I had switched back.